# Springboot logback not deleting old logfiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

Im using logback with SpringBoot but can't get it to delete old log files.

I defined the following appender in my logback-spring.xml file:

```xml
    <appender name="app" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/app.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 10 days worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

Even though I set "maxHistory" and "cleanHistoryOnStart", logfiles that are older than 10 days aren't being deleted. Neither on RollOver nor on StartUp.

Everything else seems to work fine. The logfiles are RolledOver and renamed according to the defined Rules.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what the problem was and it seems to be just a misunderstanding on my part.

I had an application running that produced logs for about 2 months already before I actually added the  tag in my logback file.

My assumption was, that logback will just delete all those older logs automatically too when I start it. That doesnt seem to be case however.

Comment: What's your solution? How do you get rid of the old log files that do not match the current (=today as yyyy-MM-dd) pattern? Do you delete them manually?

Answer (score 1):

maxHistory is not about days, it is about number of files.  See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html
and [logback deletes the logs before the MaxHistory during hourly rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998191/logback-deletes-the-logs-before-the-maxhistory-during-hourly-rollback)